# Check if key, value pair exists and return them in the row next to the match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel spreadsheet given by Tom. In that spreadsheet he has given me ~1000 key, value pairs.

```
Tom's salesID, transID: 

salesID     transID
329709765   TODPG201110131205590838
329711175   TODPG201110131206560772
329712002   TODPG201110131207560344
329713688   TODPG201110131207570066
330220683   TODPG201110210902560629
330220789   TODPG201110210903570267
2004429174  TODPG201412051415130300
```

...

In my database, I found those `transID`s, but with different `salesID`s. So, I need to merge my results with Tom's results.

Tom wants to see the differences, i.e.

```
Tom's salesID, transID:                   My salesID, transID:

B           C                             E           F                         G           
salesID     transID                       salesID     transID                   match?
329709765   TODPG201110131205590838       227841258   TODPG201110131205590838
329711175   TODPG201110131206560772       635241526   TODPG201110131206560772
329712002   TODPG201110131207560344       201452635   TODPG201110131207560344
329713688   TODPG201110131207570066       412563578   TODPG201110131207570066
330220683   TODPG201110210902560629       472541526   TODPG201110210902560629
330220789   TODPG201110210903570267       330220789   TODPG201110210903570267   match
2004429174  TODPG201412051415130300       2004429174   TODPG201412051415130300  match
```

...

There could be a match in Tom's and my `salesID`, but not that many...

This way I can show Tom that for the same `transID` his `salesID` and my `salesID` don't match. It would be even better if the formula  also said 'match' right next to the ones that do match...

Is this possible?
I have following formula but no luck so far:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$1064,MATCH(D2,$H$2:$H$1067,0),1),"no match")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VLOOKUP function to do this... the formula would be something like:

`=VLOOKUP([tom's salesID],[Your 2 columns],2,FALSE)=[your transID]`

That would return true or false, you could then make it say 'match' or whatever from there.  Note that the VLOOKUP wants the data (in this case your salesID column) to be sorted.  Do NOT change the FALSE to TRUE -- that will cause it to return the closest matching salesID.  The 2 specifies the 2nd column should be returned (your transID).

EDIT:   Sorry, I thought you were comparing salesIDs for matching transIDs but you're going the other direction.  VLOOKUP uses the first column in the array as the index, so you'd have to swap columns B/C and E/F, but then you could do:

`=IFERROR(  IF(VLOOKUP(E3,B$3:C$999,2,FALSE)=F3,"match","no match")  ,"transID not found")`

I added a bit that will also tell you whether your transID is just missing from Tom's list.

[image: example]

Comment: From what I understood, you are saying like this: =VLOOKUP(B2:B1064,E2:F1064,2,FALSE)=F2:F1064. this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to get at.  Try this (with your data in column B,C, E, F):

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$9,MATCH(E3&F3,$B$3:$B$9&$C$3:$C$9,0))),"","Match")
```

Enter as an array (press <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

[image]

The main part is the index/matching, with two parameters

```
INDEX($E$3:$E$9,MATCH(E3&F3,$B$3:$B$9&$C$3:$C$9,0))
```

I'm using what is in E & F to match against the column B and C ranges.  You can use index/match, matching multiple parameters, just by connecting them with `&`, as you can see.  If that's not quite what you needed, I think you can see how to tweak - but if not, let me know!