# In Excel, is there a way to make logical comparisons between a set of cell and another set of cells (like conceptually comparing key-value pairs)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Assumptions/Background:**

- There is an excel spreadsheet.
- The excel spreadsheet has columns, labelled Alphabetically.
- The excel spreadsheet has rows, labelled numerically.
- Combined, the cell located via a column and row label is the corresponding alphanumeric characters concatenated.

**Situation:**

- Now, consider this spreadsheet has 4 Columns.
- These 4 columns and are labelled as to as Column A, Column B, Column C, and Column D, from left to right, in the order named, in series:
- Treat rows of Column A and Column B as rows of key-value pairs for key-value set #1.
- Treat rows of Column C and Column D as rows of key-value pair for key value set #2.

**Question:**

- Question 1: How does one compare Key-value pair #1 with corresponding Key-value pair #2 in the same row?
- Question 2 (Constraint on Question 1): How does one do this without transforming and codifying the data from both cells of the first conceptual key-value pair.

Comment: You would need to give an example of the data or atleast explain what it is that you are trying to compare.

Comment: To answer your question: "Yes, there is". To make your question more useful, please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

[image: Is this what you mean?]

If so, you simply type this kind of formula in the top most cell and drag it down all the way to your last value. Quick and dirty.

```
=IF(A2=C2,IF(B2=D2,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Otherwise, here is another approach:

[image: You can also use this kind of formula if the key/value pairs aren't required to be on the same line:]

```
=IFERROR(  IF(VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$999,2,FALSE)=D2,"match","no match"),"Not found")
```

CREDIT to AC who provided the second part of the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303583/22876455

Comment: I think so! Nested If statement for the win! Thank you. I'm rusty. Happy with quick-and-dirty. IF there are any functions, I'd be interested but this is great, thanks.

Comment: You can also have a look at this formula which takes a different approach. It will, for instance, allow to match key:value even if they aren't on the same line. See my example:

=IFERROR(  IF(VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$999,2,FALSE)=D2,"match","no match"),"Not found")

Comment: Thank you. So, error handling + conditional VLookup. Sounds good!

I will have to think about it to understand the intuition here but it looks like that would work. 

I'll remove the accepted answer check to allow for more answers to upvote. I also changed my question and the background to be more clear. Its hard to add details when there's a moderator with 50k points gatekeeping and shrinking the text, but get nagged for being minimalistic cus the mod isn't a computer science guy and its less work to break a castle than it is to make a castle (Cut down text vs adding their own text).

Comment: I don't understand. Does the answer provided fits your need or it doesn't? If not, what's missing?

Comment: No, sorry, your answer is great. I'm new too so maybe I don't understand how this all works. You're definitely the favourite for the gold!